# Change the color of the active tab (and the rest to normal) in facebook(fbml) application

Tags: javascript, html, fbml

I have been working all day but unable to achieve this : It is a very common form of theming the navigation tabs. 
 What I am trying to do is to change the color of the active (ie selected tab ) keeping the rest of the tabs to normal css configuration using css and javascript. I am trying to do it in facebook application. 
 This is the javascript code

`function myFunction(element)
         {

           var liArray = document.getElementById("menu").childNodes;
            
var i=0;
            
while(liArray[i])
            {
                
liArray[i].id="";
                
i++;
            }

            element.id="active";

            }`

where the "active" is the id associated with the "color changing css" (not shown here)

The html code where the above script is applied is  as follows.

```
    <ul id="menu" class = "orange">
        <li onClick="myFunction(this);"><a href="#" clicktoshow="nav1" clicktohide="nav2,nav3">Home</a></li>
        <li onClick="myFunction(this);"><a href="#" clicktoshow="nav2" clicktohide="nav1,nav3">Invite your friends</a></li>
        <li onClick="myFunction(this);"><a href="#" clicktoshow="nav3" clicktohide="nav1,nav2">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

But its not working. Its also not showing any error. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change ID of elements.. dunno how wrong it is but it surely not good idea.

Change the `class` instead:

```
function myFunction(element) {
   //get all list items:
   var liArray = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");

    //make all items inactive
    for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length; i++)
        liArray[i].className = "inactive";

    //make clicked item active:
    element.className = "active";
}
```

In the CSS, where you now have something like `#menu #active` change it to `#menu .active`